# Доступ к пользователю по ID (MemberShipUser GetUserById)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Доступ к работе с пользователем можно получить через GetUser("Имя пользователя"), а можно как-то получить того же пользователя, если имеется, скажем, его ID?

Answer (score 1):

используя **LINQ to SQL**, создаём **DataContext** c таблицей **aspnet_Users** и потом работаем в стиле:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
db.aspnet_Users.Where(user=>user.UserID == new Guid());
```

или напрямую через SqlCommand или Хранимые процедуры

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл ещё проще:

    MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(id);    

:))))